# Interface in c# issue

Tags: c#, interface

I am new in c# development. I just trying to study the interface feature. Based on the articles and notes I read about interfaces, I tried to write a sample code to implement interface based on what I understood from those notes and articles.

But when I debugging the project I got a build error

"Inconsistent accessibility: parameter type 'StartMachine' is less accessible than method 'SwitchBoard.switchPress(StartMachine)'".

What is the problem here ?. or Did I implemented the interface in correct way ? or Is my concept about interface is wrong ?..

Please help.
Thanks in advance.

I posted my code below.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        StartMachine s1 = new Machine1();
        SwitchBoard switch1 = new SwitchBoard();
        switch1.switchPress(s1);
    }
}

interface StartMachine
{
    void startMachine();
}

public class Machine1 : StartMachine
{
    public void startMachine()
    {
        HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("Machine 1 Started");
    }
}

public class Machine2 : StartMachine
{
    public void startMachine()
    {
        HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("Machine 2 Started");
    }
}

public class SwitchBoard
{
    public void switchPress(StartMachine switchNum)
    {
        switchNum.startMachine();
    }
}
```

Comment: The convention for interfaces is prefacing them with a capital "I"... really recommend you follow that convention, it will make your code much easier to read.  `IStartMachine`

Comment: Thanks jeremy. I will follow the code convention in future.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to put a `public` access modifier in front of your interface. <strike>The Machine1/2 classes are `public`, but your interface is defaulting to `internal`. This is less accessible than public.</strike>

Set interface to public access modifer:

```
public interface StartMachine {...}
```

<strike>Alternatively, you could change your classes to be:</strike>

```
internal class Machine1: StartMachine {...}
internal class Machine2: StartMachine {...}
```

For more information on access modifiers, take a look on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wxh6fsc7%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).

**Correction:**:

The `Switchboard` class and `switchPress` method are `public`. However, the `switchPress` method is attempting to access the `StartMachine.startMachine` (ugh, ambigious naming) method, which is `internal` (by default). You need to either change the `StartMachine` interface to be public, or change `Switchboard`/`switchPress` to`internal`.

Answer (score 4):

Consider the error message, you have an "inconsistent accessibility" between your method and your interface. The fix is simple, mark your interface public.

```
public interface StartMachine
```

You have a public method that accepts a `StartMachine`, yet the interface itself was not marked public. External code would be able to see the method yet not be able to provide the appropriate argument to it.

Answer (score 2):

Make your interface public.

```
public interface StartMachine 
{
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As others have said, mark the interface public. I'll add that I think the confusion here is that while all interface *members* are automatically public, the interface itself does not have to be. You can have private interfaces for use only internally to a library.